# Laravel 5.5: Ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

A weird issue happening with me & I'm being unable to figure it out.

`Ajax` form submit not working in `Laravel 5.5` although it works in `Laravel 5.2`. I mean the same code works for `Laravel 5.2` but not for `Laravel 5.5`. I'm attaching my codes so that you can understand.

`Html:`

```
<form action="{{ url('/register') }}" method="POST" id="userRegistrationForm">
    ...........
    ...........
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

`JS:`

```
$('#userRegistrationForm').validate({
    rules:{
        ......
    },
    messages:{
        ......
    },

    submitHandler: function(form){
        /* alert('Submit success!') */ /* It works, that means this function works properly */ 

        /* But this not works */
        $.ajax({
            url: form.action,
            type: form.method,
            data: $(form).serialize(),

            success: function(response){
                location.reload();
            },

            error: function(response){
                alert('error spotted');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

When I submit the registration from, JQuery validation works. But the form submits by default pattern, not by Ajax. Error not showing by Javascript alert.

Answer (score 0):

your must stop preventing write your code like this

```
    $("#userRegistrationForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }).validate({
        messages:{..},
        rules: {...},

        submitHandler: function(form) { 

           $.ajaxSetup({
               headers: {
                  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
              }
           });
           $.ajax({
              url: form.action,
              type: form.method,
              data: $(form).serialize(),

           success: function(response){
               location.reload();
           },

           error: function(response){
              alert('error spotted');
           }
        });
            return false;  //This doesn't prevent the form from submitting.
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set csrf-token on your meta tags?

`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

after your set token, you need to set headers for your ajax request, so you just need to add below code before your ajax request.

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
 $.ajax({
        url: form.action,
        type: form.method,
        ... : ...,
```